# Flask File Upload Permission Denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-uploads

I am hosting a web application on my server 8Ubuntu 18.04 using Flask.

The goal of my application is to upload a upload a picture (or any kind of files for now). However, when attempting to upload a file to the img folder I get permissions error :

```
 ERROR:cloud:Exception on / [POST], referer: http://192.168.1.35/
 Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     raise value, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/var/www/cloud/cloud/__init__.py", line 15, in upload_image, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename)), referer: http://192.168.1.35/
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3066, in save, referer: http://192.168.1.35/
     dst = open(dst, "wb"), referer: http://192.168.1.35/
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/cloud/cloud/static/img/uploads/3E5A33B5-7E19-461A-B0C5-6835080675E7.jpeg', referer: http://192.168.1.35/
 , referer: http://192.168.1.35/
 AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
 AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
 AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

So I understand that there is a permission Error. How is it possible to fix this ?

My file structure is the following:

[image]

My code (python3) for `__init__.py` is the following :

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"] = "/var/www/cloud/cloud/static/img/uploads"


@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            image = request.files["image"]
            print(image)
            image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename))
            return "IMAGE SAVED"
    return render_template('upload-image.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and for upload-image.html i is the following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>HELLO</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <h1>This is a test</h1>
   <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name = "image" id="image">
            <label for="image">Select Image</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not get this error when it is working locally but only when I deploy t so that it is accessible on the computers in the same LAN as mine.

This is the tutorial I am following : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WruncSoCdI

Answer (score 0):

Give 777 permission to folder in server where you want to upload files.

Comment: So to the var file or only uploads file ?

Comment: To the uploads file not var file.

Comment: Never advice anybody to set permissions to 777, especially not beginners.

Comment: why ? Or do you have any other option ?. I give that advice because he only needs to upload file not other staff.

Comment: The alternative is to set correct permissions. In order to be able to give detailed advice we need to know more about the setup.

Answer (score -1):

This is the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/cloud/cloud/static/img/uploads/3E5A33B5-7E19-461A-B0C5-6835080675E7.jpeg', referer: http://192.168.1.35/
```

That is an error originating from the operating system, saying that you do not have the permission to create a file in that directory.

Now, when I say *"you"* don't have the permission, I mean the user which is running the process. Which user that is depends on the configuration of the server.

You can run `chown` to change the owner of the directory, so that it is owned by the user which is going to access it, or you can go for a simpler option, which is to allow everyone to write to that directory, if you don't mind the security risk:

```
chmod 777 /var/www/cloud/cloud/static/img/uploads
```

Comment: Never change permissions to 777. Please do not advice beginners to do this.

Comment: @J.G. I did write _"if you don't mind the security risk"_ and I did offer a different option with `chown`.

Comment: Would you advice somebody, who is not able to judge the situation,  to drive a car without brakes? I am sorry. Bad advice stays bad advice. Endangering the server is no acceptable workaround. I know. You only want to help. Unfortunately, there is no shortcut to host a web application on your own server.

Comment: @J.G. Please refrain from starting arguments and provide a better answer if you think the existing ones are not good enough. Saying "that is no good" to every offered solution, withut offering a better one, does not help anyone.

Comment: I already created an answer before I commented here. There is not much to add. Without all information available (user/group of process, user/group of directory, permission of directory) it is impossible to give a specific answer. We have to wait until @lolaa answers my requests. Please do not take this personal - it was never meant to be. Setting up web servers and creating web applications is my job since the nineties. This certainly does not mean I know everything, but maybe take into account theoretically I could be right. All the best!

Answer (score -1):

You have to adjust the permissions for this folder.

This can be done with a combination of `chmod` to set permissions and `chown` to change the owner/group of the folder.

If you have trouble to fix this on your own, please show us the current permissions / ownership.

And also you need to know which user is running your Flask app.

Comment: If this app will be available online in the future what do you recommend I do for the permissions ?

Comment: As I wrote above. We need to know more about your setup.